# Can't I use Mybatis' resultMap's association and collection together?

Tags: collections, associations, dto, spring-mybatis

The team table and the schdule table are in a 1:n relationship.
I made a select query showing the reservation details of team as below.

```
    <select id="getTeamSchdules" resultMap="teamResultMap">
        select a.team_id, a.team_name, b.sche_date
        from team a, schedule b
        where 1 = 1
          and a.STADIUM_ID = b.stadium_id
          and a.team_id = #{teamId}
    </select>
```

The contents of the select query result were mapped to mybatis resultMap as follows:

```
    <resultMap id="teamResultMap" type="com.example.api.domain.team.domain.TeamSchedulerInfo">
        <association property="team" javaType="com.example.api.domain.team.domain.Team">
            <result property="teamId" column="team_id"/>
            <result property="teamName" column="team_name" />
        </association>
        <collection property="dates" column="stadium_id" javaType="list" ofType="string">
            <result column="sche_date" />
        </collection>
    </resultMap>
```

And the Java pojo class and controller is as follows.

```
@Data
public class Team {

    private String teamId;
    private String teamName;
}


@Data
public class TeamSchedulerInfo {

    private Team team;
    private List<String> dates;
}
```

The question here is that when I print out the result of the query as an API response, it comes out as follows.

```
[
    {
        "team": {
            "teamId": "K04",
            "teamName": "UNITED"
        },
        "dates": [
            "20120324"
        ]
    },
    {
        "team": {
            "teamId": "K04",
            "teamName": "UNITED"
        },
        "dates": [
            "20120414"
        ]
    },
    {
        "team": {
            "teamId": "K04",
            "teamName": "UNITED"
        },
        "dates": [
            "20121117"
        ]
    }
]
```

This is not the result I expected.
Here, I want to show one Team object result and date in the form of a List.
The JSON API response results I want are as follows.

```
[
    {
        "team": {
            "teamId": "K04",
            "teamName": "UNITED"
        },
        "dates": [
            "20120324",
            "20120414",
            "20121117"
        ]
    }
]
```

In other words, I want one team object and the date reserved in that team to appear in list form.

How do I deal with it? Can't I use the association and collection of resultMap together? Or did I use it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To aggregate rows returned from a joined query, you need to specify proper `<id />` in the result map.

```xml
<resultMap id="teamResultMap"
    type="com.example.api.domain.team.domain.TeamSchedulerInfo">
  <id column="team_id" />
  <association property="team"
      javaType="com.example.api.domain.team.domain.Team">
    <id property="teamId" column="team_id" />
    <result property="teamName" column="team_name" />
  </association>
  <collection property="dates" column="stadium_id"
      javaType="list" ofType="string">
    <id column="sche_date" />
  </collection>
</resultMap>
```

The first `<id>` does not have a `property` attribute because there is no corresponding property in `TeamSchedulerInfo`.
Still, MyBatis needs it to identify the object.

`<id />` in `<association />` and `<collection />` are not required, but it's good for performance.

Note that this result map assumes `sche_date` is unique (i.e. there can be no doubleheader ⚾️).
If this is not what you want, you need to specify a proper column as `<id />` (e.g. schedule id).